# python click passing multiple key values as options

Tags: python-click

I am using `python-click` and I would like to pass values with a format like this

```
myprogram mycommand --parameter param1=value1 --parameter param2=value2
```

I was looking at [click option documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#multiple-options) but I can't find any construct that could help with this, the only solution I can find is invoking a `callback` function and check that the string is properly constructed `<key>=<value>`, then elaborate the values properly.

Nothing bad in that solution, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to handle this since the pattern looks to be common enough.

Answer (score 2):

So, I've had a go at it. I've managed to do it the following ways.

Firstly, I've tried this, though it doesn't satisfy the `--parameter` criteria.

```py
@click.command("test")
@click.argument("args", nargs=-1)
def test(args):
    args = dict([arg.split("=") for arg in args])
    print(args)
```

so when invoking like `test param1=test1 param2=test` the output is:

```
{'param1': 'test1', 'param2': 'test2' }
```

Secondly, I thought about a multiple option, combined with a variadic argument, which seems to be closer to your requirements:
`test -p param1=test -p param2=test`

```py
@click.command("test")
@click.option('-p', '--parameter', multiple=True)
@click.argument("args", nargs=-1)
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    param_args = kwargs['parameter']
    param_args = dict([p.split('=') for p in param_args])
    print(param_args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

The output will be the same as the previous case.

If you were to `print(kwargs['parameter'])`, you'd get

```
('param1=test', 'param2=test')
```

It sounds a bit more cleaner than using a callback, but not by much. Still, hope it helps.